# ios private api - refresh wifi proxy settings

Tags: ios, api, private, jailbreak, socks

I'm trying to set pac file setting to change socks connection on ios device by edit SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

```
[Proxies setObject:@1 forKey:@"ProxyAutoConfigEnable"];
[Proxies setObject:@"file:///private/var/proxy.pac" forKey:@"ProxyAutoConfigURLString"];
```

Pac file:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    return "SOCKS 192.168.1.13:12345";
}
```

I can see the change in Setting -> Wifi -> Wifi SSID

But it only effect if I turn off and turn on again

How can I refresh wifi setting after change preferences.plist without turn off and turn on again?

Sorry for my bad English!